# aberrant shuffling behaviour from dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset, shuffle

Let us suppose I am importing an image dataset using "image_dataset_from_directory" with **no labels**, with the shuffling argument set to True.

```
  train_ds, val_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    my_data_folder,
    label_mode=None,
    seed=123,
    image_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    validation_split=0.4,
    subset='both',
    shuffle=True) # when True, only the training set is shuffled
```

Afterwards, I want to keep track of the file paths I imported, so I used "file_paths" property. Because the file paths are not in batches, I had to do the following:

```
file_paths_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_ds.file_paths).batch(32)
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_ds, file_paths_dataset))
```

Seems everything is OK. But now the shuffling starts. Everytime I access train_ds, it is shuffled. When I say "access", I am referring to one of the following options:

```
next(iter(train_ds))
```

```
for this_batch in train_ds:
```

```
print(list(train_ds))[batch]
```

All these options reshuffle the dataset.

The problem is the following: only the first column (with the images) is shuffled. The paths are not shuffled, and now they are **unsynced with the respective images**.

Honestly, I cannot see any appication where it is usefull to shuffle independently columns of a dataset.
Now, imagine I was adding not the list of paths, but a list of labels? When I trained the data, everything would be messed up.

Anyway, I believe shuffling should be applied to all columns of a dataset. This is done with I import a labeled dataset, but not when I merge datasets using the zip method.
I also don't know how to print my dataset in a reproductive way other than setting shuffle=False when importing the data. I don't want to do it, because of the following statement I found in Keras documentation when using **model.fit**:

shuffle: Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). This argument is **ignored** when x is a generator or an object of tf.data.Dataset.

[link](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)

So if I set shuffle to False, and **because I used a generator**, the argument is ignored and this means I cannot shuffle the data when training my model. Thats not what I want. I want to shuffle ONLY when training my model, and not otherwise.

Maybe I am doing something wrong and there is a better way to do this. I don't know. Anyone knows a workaround? I want my file path list to be synced with the respective images all the time.

Best regards

Comment: Just use `train_ds.shuffle()` after zipping, I don't see what the big deal is here. You can also keep a reference to the unshuffled one for iteration etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is I want to shuffle every epoch when training. I believe train_ds.shuffle() only shuffles once before the training starts. Is there any other workaround that does not involve using a custom fit?

Comment: No, `Dataset.shuffle()` re-shuffles every epoch by default.